# Azure Emulator appears to hang on Web Role startup

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services, azure-emulator

I am trying to use the Azure emulator to debug a .net solution for VS2013, I am using IIS Express and Emulator Express.  The project contains several worker roles, which start just fine, and one web roles that seems to hang intermittently. The weird thing is that if I reboot the computer and restart the debugger, it seems to work.

I see the following lines if I click on the "Show Compute Emulator UI" option, Web Role:

> [fabric] Role Instance: deployment28(2907).MyApp.Cloud.MyApp.Web.0
>
> [fabric] Role state Unhealthy

When it hangs, I can go to make an initial API call while the dialog is still displaying and see the Unhealthy error message displaying, I receive a response from the API call which would indicate the web role is running even though it is saying the role state is unhealthy and the dialog is still displaying.  As a side note, before it returns I see a lot of Loading symbol messages on the lower left of the screen that usually displays a Ready message.

Here is the dialog that is displaying:

[image]

1) Why is it hanging if it is able to receive requests?

2) What is a way to troubleshoot a problem like this when you are using the IIS Express and emulator express?

3) What could be the cause of this problem and what are possible solutions?

Comment: I have a quite similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926079/role-in-azure-compute-emulator-stuck-cycling-between-unknown-and-destroyed-state

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?